# Crear array de arrays en bucle

Tags: python, numpy

Estoy intentando guardar en una variable (Uc) los valores de un array de 8x21 (U) en cada iteracción de un bucle. El bucle en cada iteracción me genera unos valores distintos dentro de U y me gustaría guardar esos valores en Uc por cada interacción, de tal manera que si hago por ejemplo Uc[4] el resultado sea un array de 8x21.

¿Alguno sabría cómo hacerlo?

Estoy pasando el código desde MATLAB, que utiliza una estructura de celdas:

```
for i=1:50
% Código que genera una U con números aleatorios de tamaño 8x21
% ...
Uc{i}=U;
    if i > 1
        if abs(max(max(Uc{i} - Uc{i-1}))) < min_impro, break; end
end
```

Realmente el cómo se haya la U en este caso da igual, ya que lo que quiero es que sus valores se guarden en Uc.

Comment: Hola, no estaría mal que releyeras [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Al menos indica que pasos has seguido y donde te has estancado o se te ha presentado el problema para qle que pides ayuda.

Comment: he editado la pregunta @Juan a ver si sabrías darme una solución, gracias

Comment: quieres que en la variable `Uc` se almacenen n arrays de 8x21??

Comment: exacto @Christian, me gustaría que se fueran añadiendo arrays hasta que se cumpliera la condición que hace que se termine de iterar (en MATLAB, el numero de interaciones es 50 pero se llega (al menos con un conjunto dado de U's) a 30.

Comment: y que datos contiene el array de 8x21??

Comment: son números entre 0 y 1 de tipo float64

Comment: Pues me quedo igual, o peor. Entiendo que tienes un array de 8 filas por 21 columnas y quieres guardarlo en otro array también de 8 x21 ¿?

Comment: No, no, lo que quiero es que mientras el bucle itere, se cree la variable Uc rellenándose de U, de tal manera que sea así:
- Iteración 1: Uc = [U]
- Iteración 2: Uc = [U, U]
- Iteración 3: Uc = [U, U, U]
Las U son diferentes en cada iteración por unos procesos que también hace el bucle que realmente no son necesarios para dar con la solución. El tamaño que tienen tampoco importa realmente. Lo que he escrito no tiene por qué estar bien pero sí refleja lo que quiero hacer, de tal manera que si hago Uc[4] me devuelva la U que surgió en la Iteración 4.

Comment: Es por ello que a priori no se sabe el tamaño de Uc, pero en MATLAB siempre es de tamaño 1xM (esa M variará según procesos fuera del bucle ajenos al problema que quiero solucionar, ya que sólo es informativo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una lista vacía `Uc=[]` y añade a la misma cada `U` que vayas generando en el bucle, mediante `Uc.append(U)`.

Por ejemplo, voy a generar 6 iteraciones y en cada una un array de 8x21 con numeros aleatorios que varían entre 0 y 100 para la primera iteración, entre 100 y 200 para la segunda, etc.

```
import numpy as np

Uc = []

for i in range(6):
  U = np.random.randint(i*100, (i+1)*100, size=(8,21))
  Uc.append(U)
```

En `Uc` tienes lo que pedías. Por ejemplo veamos qué tamaño y qué valores tiene `Uc[4]`:

```
>>> Uc[4].shape
(8, 21)

>>> Uc[4]
array([[425, 416, 499, 477, 417, 470, 456, 489, 433, 440, 421, 437, 413, 438, 486, 448, 465, 467, 403, 427, 415],
       [429, 492, 416, 471, 454, 417, 442, 437, 458, 492, 493, 428, 474, 406, 483, 497, 404, 420, 437, 437, 470],
       [410, 487, 402, 411, 488, 452, 475, 439, 487, 413, 413, 421, 418, 480, 437, 454, 440, 482, 469, 454, 496],
       [469, 403, 459, 428, 414, 465, 466, 467, 403, 488, 443, 449, 488, 414, 475, 474, 441, 451, 477, 470, 422],
       [467, 427, 425, 419, 438, 475, 418, 412, 412, 434, 482, 411, 407, 488, 418, 467, 496, 479, 438, 488, 496],
       [494, 499, 481, 405, 463, 400, 403, 467, 497, 471, 496, 415, 472, 475, 471, 438, 433, 402, 434, 401, 460],
       [402, 480, 462, 476, 401, 443, 457, 428, 495, 417, 453, 454, 463, 478, 411, 493, 430, 481, 455, 433, 413],
       [409, 453, 451, 401, 421, 459, 407, 426, 424, 484, 462, 420, 440, 437, 443, 461, 426, 491, 465, 485, 456]])
```

Ahora bien, `Uc` no es un array numpy sino una lista. Si quieres puedes convertirlo en array:

```
>>> Uc = np.array(Uc)
>>> Uc.shape
(6, 8, 21)
```

Comment: Curiosamente se me acababa de ocurrir esta solución pero tu me la has explicado mejor! muchas gracias!